# Project vector onto r-Z plane

Tags: vector-spaces, projective-geometry

I have a normal vector 'n' in 3D space and the point on the surface from which is calculated in Cartesian coordinates x,y,z. I would like to project the point and the normal cylindrically onto the θ=0 plane following the rule (x,y,z) --> (r,Z)= =(sqrt{x^2+y^2} , z) in order to calculate the length of the normal vector before and after the projection. Is there an easy formula for this?

Comment: What is the "r-Z plane" and what is the "circumferencial dimension" ? These name are not at all classical.

Comment: JeanMarie, I have edited the question to make clearer.

Comment: Thonks for the editing. If I understand well, it's projecting on the $z$-axis. In this case, it amonts to the dot product of $n=(n_x,n_y,n_z)$ with the unit directing vector of this axis, i.e., $(0,0,1)$, i.e., $n_x*0+n_y*0+n_z*1=n_z$ which the length you are looking for.